# Issues with IconButton transparency when animated with AnimatedVisibility in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have two IconButtons in a Row. The second is hidden and only shown when the first one is clicked. What I cannot figure out is how to preserve the first button's background transparency when the other is shown via AnimatedVisibility. See GIF below.

[image: IconButton background not transparent]

This is my current code:

```
Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(32.dp)
) {
    var isClicked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            isClicked = !isClicked
        },
        modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp)
    ) {
        val icon: ImageVector = if (isClicked) {
            Icons.Filled.NotStarted
        } else {
            Icons.Filled.PauseCircle
        }
        Icon(
            imageVector = icon,
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp)
        )
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isClicked,
    ) {
        IconButton(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 24.dp)
                .size(64.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.StopCircle,
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first button is still transparent, cropping effect is caused of `AnimatedVisibility` clipping view to bounds during animation. This is default behaviour.

To redefine it just pass `clip = false` to `expandHorizontally`/`shrinkHorizontally`:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = isClicked,
    enter = fadeIn() + expandHorizontally(clip = false),
    exit = fadeOut()  + shrinkHorizontally(clip = false),
    modifier = Modifier
) {
```

Result:

[image]